# Mapping custom fields to CiviCRM's standard fields

Tags: caldera-forms, aws

I have hired a freelancer to create CiviCRM Sign-Up form featuring Tell-A-Friend and validation email.

Using CiviCRM contact Caldera Processor, he created the form shown below but has an integration problem -  is not able to map created custom fields "Province" and "Municipality" into CiviCRM's standard fields "State/Province" and "City".

He is not able to use the standard fields as they do not allow him to have 2 pull-down menus (Province and Municipality – see picture below) and other features (Tell-A-Friend and verification email). Your comments and suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

[Note: Selecting a Province immediately populates the Municipality field.]

Environment: WordPress 5.2.2 and CiviCRM 5.15.1 hosted at AWS.

[image]

Answer (score 5):

The freelancer wasn't familiar enough with CiviCRM to realize that the municipality field we were looking for was already an integrated part of the CiviCRM through the county field.

Comment: Glad you found your answer!  Consider hiring from the [CiviCRM partner listing](https://civicrm.org/partners-contributors) - not only will you be getting folks who know CiviCRM well, you can also support folks who financially support the software, which is necessary to keep its quality high.